# Encoding: exporting special characters from an excel spreadsheet into a php array

Tags: php, excel, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to get the information from an excel spreadsheet into a PHP array.
The problem being that the entries in the spreadsheet include special accented characters such as á and ž etc.

The first thing I did is to export the spreadsheet as a .txt file. I made sure to click on tools --> web options, in order to set the character encoding to UTF-8.

When I opened the .txt file with notepad or notepad++ many (but not all) of the accented characters were replaced with '?'.

for example:
Zlatan Ibrahimović ----> Zlatan Ibrahimovi?

However, some of the characters remained unaffected:
Carlos Tévez

Furthermore, when I attempted to import the .txt file into a PHP array, the remaining characters turned into question marks aswell!

The following code, is intended to print the first 4 names in the list:

```
$file = fopen("players/player_names.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

$line_array = array();
$x = 0;
while(!feof($file))
{
array_push($line_array, fgets($file));
}
fclose($file);

$name_array = array();

for ($i =1; $i < 4; $i++ )
{
echo $line_array[$i];
echo "<br/>";   
}
```

However, the following is displayed:

Sergio Ag�ero 
Zlatan Ibrahimovi? 
Carlos T�vez 
Luis Su�rez

It appears that the normal question marks '?' are being produced in the transfer from excel to .txt, and the black background question marks of the remaining accented characters '�' are being produced when importing the .txt file to PHP.

I have made sure the character encoding of the PHP file is set to UTF-8 with the following:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Where am I going wrong!?

Thanks for your help in advance :).

Comment: What you describe sounds like you didn't save the text file in UTF-8 encoding. Install OpenOffice or LibreOffice, load the spreadsheet and save as CSV. Specify UTF-8 as encoding. You can then use PHP's CSV functions and file objects to turn the file into an array easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code: header is not important, make sure you have in your `php.ini`

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Moreover, you can forget about the `Content-Type` header leaving this task to the webserver.
Nginx, for example, has the `charset UTF-8;` directive.